# Infinite Loop with Linked List

Tags: list, debugging, loops, linked-list, infinite-loop

So I'm working with a linked list and trying to sort it. I put random numbers into the linked list. First I find the lowest value and put it as the head and every following number builds a chain off the head  The functions at the top were for debugging purposes and I think I narrowed it down to somewhere in:

```c
if (beforeMin != NULL) 
    beforeMin->set_link(min->link());
d(4);
if (marker == NULL) {
    if (min != head) {
        min->set_link(head);
        head = min;
    }
} 
else {
    min->set_link(marker->link());
}
```

The full code is

```c
#include "node1.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

using namespace main_savitch_5;

void d(int val) 
{
    cout << val << endl;
}

void print(node* head) 
{
    node* current = head;
    int count = 0;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        cout << current->data() << " ";
        current = current->link();

        if (count++ > 10) break;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    size_t n;
    cout << "Please enter the number of values you want in the linked list: ";
    cin >> n;

    node* head = NULL;
    node* current = NULL;

    node* marker = NULL;
    node* beforeMin = NULL;
    node* min = NULL;

    node* previous = NULL;

    node* temp = NULL;

    //srand(time(NULL));
    if (n == 0) 
    { 
        cout << "Invalid" << endl; 
    }
    else 
    {
        list_head_insert(head, rand() % 1000 + 1);
        current = head;

        while (n-- > 1) 
        {
            list_insert(current, rand() % 1000);
            current = current->link();
        }

        current = head;
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            cout << current->data() << " ";
            current = current->link();
        }
        cout << endl;

        while ( (marker == NULL || marker->link() != NULL) 
                && head->link() != NULL)
        {
            d(1);
            current = (marker != NULL) ? marker->link() : head;
            min = current;
            d(2);
            print(head);
            current = current->link();
            while (current->link() != NULL) 
            {
                if (min->data() > current->data()) 
                {
                    min = current;
                    beforeMin = previous;
                }
                previous = current;
                current = current->link();
            }
            d(3);
            if (beforeMin != NULL) 
            {
                beforeMin->set_link(min->link()); 
            }
            d(4);
            if (marker == NULL) 
            {
                if (min != head) 
                {
                    min->set_link(head);
                    head = min;
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                min->set_link(marker->link());
            }
            d(5);
            if (marker != NULL) { marker->set_link(min); }
            marker = min;
            d(6);
        }

        current = head;
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            cout << current->data() << " ";
            current = current->link();
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program I get

```
Please enter the number of values you want in the linked list: 5
384 886 777 915 793 
1
2
384 886 777 915 793 
3
4
5
6
1
2
384 886 777 915 793 
3
4
5
6
1
2
384 777 886 777 886 777 886 777 886 777 886 777...
```

So it gives me my five random numbers if I put 5 as `n`, it sorts for the first 3, then it starts repeating the 2nd and 3rd lowest forever.

Any help with this would be appreciated. I've been staring at the code and I'm not getting any further at this point.

Comment: try making your code more functional, more modular - instead of one big messy while loop, make some functions for yourself and use these functions, like `find_min_node`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

At the first iteration of the loop:

- The list is `384 -> 886 -> 777 -> 915 -> 793`
- `marker` is `NULL`
- The minimum node is found to be `384`
- `beforeMin` is `NULL`

At the second iteration of the loop:

- The list is `384 -> 886 -> 777 -> 915 -> 793`
- `marker` is pointing to the `384` node
- The minimum node `min`, starting from the node after `marker`, is found to be `777`
- `beforeMin` points to `886`

We then trigger the following line of code:

```
min->set_link(marker->link());
```

Given what we know from above, this means setting the link from the min node `777` to point to the node directly after the marker node `384`, which is the `886` node.

However, the link from the `886` node is still pointing to the `777` node, so at this point you have a loop: `384 -> 886 -> 777 -> 886 -> 777 -> ...`

Your surface-level problem is that you're not removing nodes from one point of the list (e.g. `777` after `886`) before you're inserting them at another (`777` after `384`).

The best way to resolve this would be to organize your code a little better -- you've gotten good advice in the comments. Each distinct action should correspond to one function or method, rather than the entire process being one big chunk of code. This makes it a lot easier to check the code for correctness, because each small piece of code can be evaluated locally:

- Is it doing what it says it's doing (i.e. in the function name)?
- Is what it says it's doing in fact the right thing to do?